# Loopback include filter within scope works for GET but fails for POST request

Tags: loopbackjs

I have this scope defined in my order.json which has relation with branch and customer along with other properties.

```
"name": "Order",
"properties":{...},
"relations": {...},
"acls": {...},
"scope": {
  "include": [
    {"relation": "branch", "scope": { "fields": "BranchName" } }, 
    {"relation": "customer", "scope": { "fields": "CustomerName" } }
  ]
}
```

This works well as expected in all GET requests with following results

```
[
  {
    "OrderDate": "2018-01-12T17:52:21.000Z",
    "CustomerId": 39,
    "BranchId": 5,
    "CustomerRef": "Order by Phone",
    ...
    "CreatedBy": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "branch": {
      "BranchName": "aaaa",
      "id": 5
    },
    "customer": {
      "CustomerName": "xxxx",
      "id": 39
    }
  }
]
```

I was expecting a similar result, however, the response array received after a successful POST request does not include BranchName and CustomerName info from the related models.

Am I doing it correctly? or is there any other way to get back information from related models after a Create/Update operation. I am just trying to avoid another GET request immediately after Create/Update.

Comment: What do toy use to make requests? What is request URL looks like?

Comment: I wonder why do you ask that! I'll be using php curl later in production but for now I am testing with loopback explorer only and thats what it looks like:
for GET:  `curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 'http://localhost:3010/api/Order?access_token=xxx'` and for POST: `curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{ \ 
   "OrderDate": "2018-01-12T17:42:58.053Z", \ 
   "CustomerId": 39, \ 
   "BranchId": 5, \ 
   "CustomerRef": "Order by Phone", \ 
   "CreaBy": 1 \ 
 }' 'http://localhost:3010/api/Order?access_token=xxx'`

Comment: You can check with Loopback Explorer that GET and POST to `/Order` produce different results because GET is *Find all instances of the model matched by filter from the data source* and POST is *Create a new instance of the model and persist it into the data source.* So POST returns only one instance but not a list of them.

Comment: I know POST request is dealing with one single record and thats what it returns. However, I need extra info from the related models (Branch and Customer in my case). It would have helped if these name values were available in response even though the the ID values do exist in both (request and response) and I can easily fetch names by making separate requests. Actually I got confused by the documentation [As in here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Model-definition-JSON-file.html#default-scope) which says "Now, any **CRUD operation** with a query parameter runs in the default scope.."

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Operation hook [after save](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Operation-hooks.html#after-save).

```
Order.observe('after save', function(ctx, next) {
  if (ctx.instance) {

    ctx.instance.relatedmodel = someFunctionToGetRelatedModel();


  }
  next();
});
```

Whatever is inside the `ctx.instance` should be included in loopbacks responses.

You just have to figure out how to seamlessly pull the related model details, you want to include.

Comment: I am pretty sure what you suggest will get the job done, unfortunately I am very new to nodejs/loopback. Hope I'll be able to make it work soon, meanwhile, I'll appreciate if you can point me to some working example. Thanks.